# Migrating H2 configuration in Spring Batch for Spring Boot 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, h2, spring-cloud-task

I need to migrate a project from Spring Boot 2.5.3 to 2.7.3 (and, if significant, also Spring Cloud from 2020.0.3 to 2021.0.3 and Spring Batch from 4.3.3 to [4.3.6](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/4046)). The main issue is that when using Spring Batch and H2, I get this error

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'taskLifecycleListener'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: 
Could not obtain sequence value; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: 
Sequence "TASK_SEQ" not found; SQL statement:
select next value for TASK_SEQ [90036-214]
```

As there was a [H2 version upgrade](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7-Release-Notes#h2-21) the problem probably lies with my configuration, that was the following:

```
spring:
  batch.initialize-schema: embedded
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    password: password
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    platform: h2
    initialization-mode: embedded
```

I also tried to use the legacy compatibility mode in the jdbc string `jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=LEGACY`, without success.

Comment: @spencergibb actually seems a problem with spring-cloud-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my issue was trivial (I forgot to copy `cloud.task.initialize-enabled: true` in the new config), I found another significant problem: `spring.datasource.platform` was deprecated and now is `spring.sql.init.platform`.